# How to enable @AuthenticationPrincipal argument in a DGS query

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, netflix-dgs

I'm working on a Spring Boot service that has both a REST controller and a [Netflix DGS](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/) GraphQL component. REST methods are protected with Spring Security, and whenever the current username is required, I add a method argument using the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation, which gives me access to the authenticated user info:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails; 

@RestController
public class ActionController {

    @GetMapping("/getActions")
    public List<ActionResponse> getActions(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        return actionService.getActions(userDetails.getUsername());
    }

}
```

Now I want the same functionality for GraphQL methods implemented through [Netflix DGS](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/). But when I try to use the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` argument (like in the first example) it always equals `null`. The workaround I found is to manually assign the userDetails from the SecurityContextHolder:

```
import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.DgsComponent;
import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.DgsQuery;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails; 

@DgsComponent
public class ActionDatafetcher {

    @DgsQuery
    public List<Map<String, Object>> actions(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        // The following line works well:
        // userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        
        String username = userDetails.getUsername();   // ===>  NullPointerException here
        return actionService.getActionsMap(username);
    }

}
```

How can I get @AuthenticationPrincipal to work in a DgsComponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though Spring Security's [`AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.html) is in the application context, it's not picked up by DGS by default. You can achieve this by implementing DGS' own [`ArgumentResolver`](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/blob/v5.2.4/graphql-dgs/src/main/kotlin/com/netflix/graphql/dgs/internal/method/ArgumentResolver.kt) and delegating its work to Spring's `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`.

So all you need to create is this:

[Kotlin]

```kotlin
@Component
class DgsAuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver : ArgumentResolver {
    private val delegate = AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver()

    override fun supportsParameter(parameter: MethodParameter): Boolean {
        return delegate.supportsParameter(parameter)
    }

    override fun resolveArgument(parameter: MethodParameter, dfe: DataFetchingEnvironment): Any? {
        val request = (DgsDataFetchingEnvironment(dfe).getDgsContext().requestData as DgsWebMvcRequestData).webRequest as NativeWebRequest
        return delegate.resolveArgument(parameter, null, request, null)
    }
}
```

[Java]

```java
@Component
public class DgsAuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver implements ArgumentResolver {

    private final AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver delegate = new AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(@NotNull MethodParameter parameter, @NotNull DataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
        DgsContext context = ((DataFetchingEnvironmentImpl) dfe).getContext();
        DgsWebMvcRequestData requestData = (DgsWebMvcRequestData) context.getRequestData();
        NativeWebRequest request = requestData == null ? null : (NativeWebRequest) requestData.getWebRequest();
        return delegate.resolveArgument(parameter, null, request, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(@NotNull MethodParameter parameter) {
        return delegate.supportsParameter(parameter);
    }

}
```

Passing `null`s on 2n and 4th parameters is OK because they have no usage within delegated `resolveArgument` as you can check [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.6.7/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver.java#L103).

Comment: Brilliant! I tested this approach in my service - and it works! Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding that code block, but getting a cast exception at `(DgsWebMvcRequestData) context.getRequestData();`, I think the issue may be because I am using the webflux version of the DGS library so tried going down the         `ReactiveDgsContext.from(dataFetchingEnvironment);` route but have no idea how to get the NativeWebRequest object - do you have any idea how one could adapt your code block to work in a reactive context?